# Upgrade mysql odbc to 5.3 kills connections made with v5.1

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-7, odbc

I had mysql odbc 5.1 driver for a long time.  I upgraded to mysql odbc 5.3 driver (ansi and unicode).  But the Windows 7 ODBC Data Source Administrator specifically identifies all of my connectors as using mysql odbc 5.1 driver still. So trying to use them or configure them yields error message "The setup routines for the mysql odbc 5.1 driver odbc driver could not be found. Please reinstall the driver."  The install worked fine. Native mysql workbench can connect and has no problem.  I just need to tell the ODBC Data Source Administrator to switch over from the 5.1 driver to the 5.3 driver.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the 5.3 driver, install the 5.1 driver (The version you used to create the entries "long time" ago). Then remove all 5.1 DSN entries. Then uninstall 5.1 driver, install 5.3 driver and re-create the entries using the 5.3 driver.